# Maintain path constants for RestControllers

Tags: java, rest

I'd like to know whats the common style to maintain path constants for Rest Controllers.
For example you have something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = ANY_PATH_VALUE)
```

I do maintain those constants (in the example ANY_PATH_VALUE) at the moment in a class called `PathConstants` which looks like this:

```
public abstract class PathConstants {
    public static final String ANY_PATH_VALUE = "/path/{SOME_ID}";
    ...
}
```

Is it a common way to keep those values straight at the method of the RestController class or is it like I do currently? Or is there a even more common way how to maintain this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a reasonable way to maintain paths. Just make sure you always build the paths from other constants. For example, if your path has version, you define the version as another variable.

```
public static final String VERSION_1 = "/v1";
public static final String USERS_V1 = VERSION_1 + "/users";
```

Comment: API paths should be immutable or at least changed with super extra precaution to not break API contract with its clients (in the microservices world clients could be almost untraceable).

Using variables in path invites to violate this rule plus it decreases readability.

Please compare

    String PUBLIC_GET_USER_BY_ID_VERSION_1 = 'api/v1/public/users/1'

vs


    String API = 'api'
    String PUBLIC = 'public'
    String USERS = 'users'
    String VERSION_1 = '1'
    String PUBLIC_GET_USER_BY_ID_VERSION_1 = API + '/' + VERSION_1 + '/' + PUBLIC + '/' + users + '/{userId}'

Comment: SO sucks when it comes to comment formatting :(

Answer (score 4):

There are two sides to this,

It actually has close to zero performance problem. This has to something with **readability**.

- The first view is keeping the values as native strings there itself in the controllers. 
   This is more readable in the sense that you can directly check the exact API route when you enter the controller.
- The second view is keeping it in some other file with `static` constants. 
   Keeping all the routes like this actually gives you one common place where you can get to know all the API routes you currently support in your application.

I personally prefer the second i.e. keeping all the paths in a file called **APIRoutes** and further divided by domains.

```
public class APIRoutes {

    public class SYSTEM {
         public static final String HEALTH_CHECK = "api/v1/healthcheck";
         public static final String LB_HEALTH_CHECK = "lb/v1/healthcheck";
    }

    public class API {
         public static final String SAVE_X = "api/v1/save";
         public static final String GET_X = "api/v1/get";
    }

    public class CACHE {
         public static final String RELOAD_X = "cache/v1/load/x";
         public static final String RELOAD_Y = "cache/v1/load/y";
    }

}
```

This way in your **controller**, you have something like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = APIRoutes.API.SAVE_X)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using constants seems to be a quite *reasonable approach*. I would, however, define the constants in a `final` class with a `private` constructor throwing an [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AssertionError.html) to enforce *noninstantiability*:

```java
public final class PathConstants  {

    // Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
    private PathConstants() {
        throw new AssertionError("No instances for you!");
    }

    public static final String PATH_TO_FOO = "foo";
    public static final String PATH_TO_BAR = "bar";
}
```

Quoting the Item 4 from Effective Java 3<sup>rd</sup> edition from Joshua Bloch:

> Because the explicit constructor is `private`, it is inaccessible outside the class. The `AssertionError` isn’t strictly required, but it provides insurance in case the constructor is accidentally invoked from within the class. It guarantees the class will never be instantiated under any circumstances. This idiom is mildly counterintuitive because the constructor is provided expressly so that it cannot be invoked. It is therefore wise to include a comment, as shown earlier.
>
> As a side effect, this idiom also prevents the class from being subclassed. All constructors must invoke a superclass constructor, explicitly or implicitly, and a subclass would have no accessible superclass constructor to invoke.

---

You also could use something like `@RequestMapping("${foo.bar}")`, where `foo.bar` is a value defined in a [property souce](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) (such as an `application.properties` file or YAML variant).

Quoting the [Spring MVC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping):

> URI path patterns can also have embedded `${…​}` placeholders that are resolved on startup by using `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` against local, system, environment, and other property sources. You can use this, for example, to parameterize a base URL based on some external configuration.